# How to setPosition menu from the screen?

Tags: menu, cocos2d-iphone, position

How can I set my menu Sprites in the center of the screen with the usual look for menu

CCSize size = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
sprite ->setPosition(ccp(size.width, size.height));

Please help me with the (ccp(?,?))

Sprites: Start, Options, Quit for game menu

```
#include "MenuScene.h"
#include "cocos2d.h"

USING_NS_CC;
using namespace cocos2d;

CCSprite *car;

CCScene* MenuScene::scene()
{
CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();
MenuScene *layer = MenuScene::create();
scene->addChild(layer);

return scene;
}


// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool MenuScene::init()
{

// 1. super init first
if ( !CCLayer::init() )
{
    return false;
}
this->setTouchEnabled(true);
//this->schedule( schedule_selector(MenuScene::update) );

CCSize winSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
CCSize size = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
CCSize visibleSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
CCPoint origin = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleOrigin();


// add a "close" icon to exit the progress. it's an autorelease object
//    CCMenuItemImage *pCloseItem = CCMenuItemImage::create(
//                                        "CloseNormal.png",
//                                        "CloseSelected.png",
//                                        this,
//    menu_selector(MenuScene::menuCloseCallback));
//
//  pCloseItem->setPosition(ccp(origin.x + visibleSize.width -     
pCloseItem->getContentSize().width ,
//                                origin.y +  
pCloseItem->getContentSize().height));

// create menu, it's an autorelease object
//    CCMenu* pMenu = CCMenu::create(pCloseItem, NULL);
//    pMenu->setPosition(CCPointZero);
//    this->addChild(pMenu, 1);


// 3. add sprite below...

CCSprite *menuLayout = CCSprite::create("sky.png");
menuLayout->setPosition(ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2));
this->addChild(menuLayout, -1);
float aX = size.width / menuLayout->getContentSize().width;
float aY = size.height / menuLayout->getContentSize().height;
menuLayout->setScaleX(aX);
menuLayout->setScaleY(aY);

return true;
}


//callfuncN_selector(MainScene::spriteMoveFinished)
//backcalls the function spriteMoveFinished()
void MenuScene::spriteMoveFinished(CCNode* pSender)
{
CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)pSender;
this->removeChild(sprite, true);
}


void MenuScene::Menus()
{
CCSize size = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();

CCMenuItemImage *startItem = CCMenuItemImage::create("sprite.png",     
"sprite.png",this,menu_selector(MenuScene::menuCloseCallback));

startItem->setPosition(ccp(590, 450));
float aX = size.width / startItem->getContentSize().width;
float aY = size.height / startItem->getContentSize().height;
//  startItem->setScaleX(aX);
//  startItem->setScaleY(aY);

CCMenuItemImage *extraItem = CCMenuItemImage::create("sprite2.png", 
"sprite2.png",this,menu_selector(MenuScene::menuCloseCallback));

extraItem->setPosition(ccp(590,350));
//float bX = size.width / extraItem->getContentSize().width;
//float bY = size.height / extraItem->getContentSize().height;
//extraItem->setScaleX(bX);
//extraItem->setScaleY(bY);

CCMenuItemImage *optionsItem = CCMenuItemImage::create("options.png",
"options.png",this,menu_selector(MenuScene::menuCloseCallback));

optionsItem->setPosition(ccp(590, 250));
//float cX = size.width / optionsItem->getContentSize().width;
//float cY = size.height / optionsItem->getContentSize().height;
//optionsItem->setScaleX(cX);
//optionsItem->setScaleY(cY);\

CCMenuItemImage *quitItem = CCMenuItemImage::create("quit.png",
"quit.png",this,menu_selector(MenuScene::menuCloseCallback));

quitItem->setPosition(ccp(590, 150));
//  float dX = size.width / quitItem->getContentSize().width;
//  float dY = size.height / quitItem->getContentSize().height;
//  quitItem->setScaleX(dX);
//  quitItem->setScaleY(dY);

CCMenu* pMenu = CCMenu::create(startItem, extraItem, optionsItem, quitItem,  
NULL);
pMenu->setPosition(0,0);
this->addChild(pMenu, 0);

}

void MenuScene::ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event){
Menus();
}

void MenuScene::ccTouchesMoved(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event){
Menus();
}

void MenuScene::ccTouchesEnded(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event){

}

void MenuScene::ccTouchesCancelled(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* 
event){

}


void MenuScene::menuCloseCallback(CCObject* pSender)
{
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->end();

#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
exit(0);
#endif
}


 /* namespace cocos2d */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to position the menu at the center of the screen you must provide the center co-ordinates in ccl

```
   sprite ->setPosition(ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2));
```

Comment: I've done this but all of my sprites are position in one place in the center

Comment: I like to have like this http://dickersondesigns.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/GD18Annie_GameInterfaceDesign_MainMenu.jpg

Comment: hi abhineetprasad I've posted my Menu code now my problem with that is that the sprites start, ... is small but the position is now ok why is that?

Answer (score 0):

First you get window size...

```
CGSize Window_size=[[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize];
```

Now set CCMenuItem in CCMenu With position...

```
CCMenuItem *Minus_Menu_item = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"ButtonMinus.png" selectedImage:@"ButtonMinus.png" disabledImage:@"ButtonNum1.png" target:self selector:@selector(Minus_Button:)];
Minus_Menu_item.position=ccp(180, 200);
Menu_Minus=[CCMenu menuWithItems:Minus_Menu_item, nil];
Menu_Minus.position = CGPointZero;
[self addChild:Menu_Minus];
```